# Multiple mysql selects in one query and then access them separately

Tags: php, mysql

I want to execute two select queries in one go, but the data isn't related to each other so a LEFT JOIn etc. will not do.. because then I end up with data I can't use.

What I got so far is;

```
$sql .= "SELECT *,
        servertypes.id as servertypeID, 
        servertypes.name as servertypeName 
       FROM servertypes";

$sql .= " JOIN".
    " (SELECT *,
        periods.id as periodID,
        periods.daysForSorting as periodNumber,
        periods.text as periodsText
       FROM periods
       ) AS periods";

$res = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$res) die("database_error_cant_select_data : ".$sql." : ".mysql_error());
```

But now how do I access `servertypes` and `periods` separately? I think I have to stop using JOIN altogether but I wouldn't know...

To illustrate what I mean, it's something like:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res["servertypes"]))
{
    print_r($row);
    echo"<br/><br/>";
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res["periods"]))
{
    print_r($row);
    echo"<br/><br/>";
}
```

Is this possible using only one query?

Comment: Why do you want them all together? It looks like the data of both isn't related. Why don't use two separated queries?

Comment: Why are you using "SELECT *"? You should list the columns explicitly.

Comment: @Nico Just wondering if it's possible really... less queries = always better but it won't matter if it can't be done. Again, just curious.

Comment: @natli less queries is better when the queries data are related, if they are not related, then make 2 queries and avoid issues ;)

Comment: You can use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) if there are the same number of columns, otherwise, you can't do this in MySQL. You can use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to force the same number of columns, but that's probably going too far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you could do something like that IF both query return the same column number

```
Table1
-----------
ProductID
Price
Qty

Table2
-----------
ProductID
Price
Qty

$Query = '(SELECT "Table1" AS Source, * FROM Table1) UNION (SELECT "Table2" AS Source, * FROM Table2)';

$Data = array('T1' => array(), 'T2' => array());
while($Assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($Query)){
    switch(strtoupper($Assoc['Source'])){
        case 'TABLE1':
            $Data['T1'][] = $Assoc;
            break;

        case 'TABLE2':
            $Data['T2'][] = $Assoc;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

//  $Data['T1'] now hold everything from Table1
//  $Data['T2'] now hold everything from Table2
```

But here, nothing is related. So to answer your question : no you cannot do what you want.

Comment: You can do this only if both tables have the same number of columns, otherwise it'll give an error

Comment: Can't be done then.. too bad. Still learned something new though, so thanks ;)

Comment: Name doesnt matter the query will take only the name on the first `SELECT`, but if you have a query with 3 columns, and another with 4 it'll give an error. "The column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the column names for the results returned." from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html

Comment: Nico is correct. It has to be the same number of columns, not name. It will use the name from the first result.

Answer (score 1):

Check out multi_query() / use_result() / next_result() functions, here is example:

http://www.robert-gonzalez.com/2007/06/01/mysql-multiple-result-procs-in-php/

Ideally I'd stay away from needing to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to join the data in one query. Entities that you're trying to join are absolutely different and have no links to each other. If you work with them separately, do separate queries

Answer (score 0):

If they must be selected together (to avoid a race condition) then you should use a transaction.

```
begin transaction;
.....queries....
commit;
```